# My first app on google play store show me this

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, android-studio

Someone who can help me to fix this problem. (NoSuchMethodError) I really don't understand this error.

I have found similar problems on the web, but none of the posted solutions appear to work. Someone who can help me. 
EDIT: I AM already working on Android Studio.
[My screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxkNw.png)
[Other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCBrH.png)

```
package com.example.android.xxxxxxxxxxy;
  import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String mActivityTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);



    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

             // The firstbutton (song).

    assert adView != null;
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    final MediaPlayer happy_birthday_to_me = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.happy_birthday_to_me);

    Button playsongmeow = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play_song_meow);

    assert playsongmeow != null;
    playsongmeow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            happy_birthday_to_me.start();

        }
    });

             // The secondbutton (song).

    assert adView != null;
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    final MediaPlayer birthday = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.birthday);

    Button playsongmeoww = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play_song_meoww);

    assert playsongmeoww != null;
    playsongmeoww.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            birthday.start();

        }
    });


             // The thirdbutton (song).

    assert adView != null;
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    final MediaPlayer happy = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.happy);

    Button playsongmeowww = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play_song_meowww);

    assert playsongmeowww != null;
    playsongmeowww.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            happy.start();

        }
    });


          // The fourthbutton (song).

    assert adView != null;
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    final MediaPlayer original = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.original);

    Button playsongmeowwww = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play_song_meowwww);

    assert playsongmeowwww != null;
    playsongmeowwww.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            original.start();

        }
    });

}

private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = {"Songs", "Photos", "Videos", "About"};
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            switch (position) {
                case 0: //Log History
                    Intent MainActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(MainActivity);
                    break;
                case 1: //Log History
                    Intent Photos = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Photos.class);
                    startActivity(Photos);
                    break;
                case 2: //Log History
                    Intent Videos = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Videos.class);
                    startActivity(Videos);
                    break;
                case 3: //Log History
                    Intent About = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
                    startActivity(About);
                default:
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setupDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("List Menu");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

           // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {

            // Inflate your main_menu into the menu.

            int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id){
        case R.id.about:


            Intent About = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
            startActivity(About);

            break;
    }

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.rate:

            // Open this Uri.

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exafmpflle.android.happybirthdayyyy&hl=en"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

            break;
    }

    switch (id){
        case R.id.privacy:

            // Open this Uri.

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DEBh3j3LG5WaF9nT9Gl2hpswa3yD-36MfPhVo3S_p08/edit"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

            break;
    }

    // Activate the navigation drawer toggle

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be saying that one of the methods that you are overriding is nonexistent. Try double checking the spellings of the methods that you are overriding.

If this helps, please consider marking this post as an answer.